Local video uploading plugin for CKEditor 5
I'm working on setting up functionality for CKEditor 5 to upload local videos to the server. In our project, we are using CKEditor 5 version 41.1.0. None of the existing plugins from NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ckeditor5%20video) are functioning properly.
At the moment, I'm adapting a solution from https://github.com/Technologie-Visao/ckeditor5-video for our project. However, I've integrated its source code into my project instead of using it as a dependency. While I've managed to enable video uploading, the resizing feature isn't working.
Does anyone know of an alternative solution? I need to be able to upload and resize videos within the editor, similar to the base functionality for images.
